# Socket.io 1.4.5 How do you send a message to an individual client in a room?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have been looking through all the answers on how to sent to a specific client here and I have not found one that works.

I have a namespace that has a room that has 2 clients in it. I have a process that wants to send information specific to 1 of the clients in that room. I have the socketID. So when I try:

```
namespace.to(socketID).emit('messageID',data);
```

I literally see nothing. I have a listener set up on the client side:

```
namespace.on('messageID', function(data) {
   console.log('messageID seen');
   console.log(data);
});
```

It never fires. I have also tried:

```
namespace.to(socketID).emit('messageID',data);
```

and

```
namespace.sockets.sockets[socketID].emit('messageID',data);
```

and

```
namespace.clients[socketId].emit('messageID',data);
```

None of them work.

So what is the right way to send a message to a specific client in a room in a namespace in socket.io version 1.4.5?

Any help would be appreciated!

Z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution to my question was to create another room and have it only have an individual client in that room.  That works perfectly.

Comment: You can also just store a reference to that client's socket when the client connects, and use it later as you need to via `socket.emit()`.  No need to create another room for just that client this way.

Comment: How would I go about doing so?

Comment: Hard to type in a comment, but in `io.on('connection', function(socket) { /* here */ }`, store a reference to the `socket` object however you like (perhaps having one global array of all connected clients).  From that point on, you can just call that object's `emit()` function wherever you like via the reference you stored.